# Time taken in connecting while audio streaming in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, shoutcast

I am using simple audio streaming in android app like this:

```
    try   {
    MediaPlayer media = new MediaPlayer();
    media.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
    media.setDataSource("http://indiespectrum.com:9000");
    media.prepare();
    media.start();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Getting Exception
}
```

Where I am using four different URL .When I start the radio streaming it takes a while to start playing.Sometimes it takes 5-6 sec and sometimes around 40-45 sec to start playing the radio. I just want to know if I can speed up these time taken .As all of these uses Shoutcast is there anyway I could speed up the connection or it depends on some kind of bitrate or something.Please help?

Comment: Simple Answer: It depends on your connectivity speed.

Comment: Why are you using prepare() to play an audio stream? You should be using prepareAsync().

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed up things a lot is leveraging the UIMain thread and doing the audiostreaming using [AsyncTask](https://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html&ei=HSpyUbmuD4KrPJ7ogPgO&usg=AFQjCNE8gLVXz1Hwq4rI8oxRkZNHjhRzpQ&bvm=bv.45512109,d.ZWU), wich enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

Comment: I have tried this but same result .... I am doing most of the work in a different thread...